# Python ide for remote debugging/coding on Raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, ssh, remote

Is there any Python Ide available from which we can remotely connect to pi (using `ssh`) and can write python script or debug from windows. I have already done this using eclipse [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/70018/remotely-debug-python-code-on-pi-using-eclipse-in-windows)but this connection also has an issue wherein it does not support the `intellisense` and thus auto complete does not work.

Is there an alternative where we can have autocomplete functionality as well as write and debug Python scripts from Windows to Pi? Please help. Thanks

Comment: Current version of VSCode has a remote function. I have had a look at it, but can't remember if it supports remote debugging.

Comment: Be interesting to see if the Pi 4 runs VSC well now https://code.headmelted.com/ but remote debugging is available and the last walkthrough I used was https://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioCodeRemoteDevelopmentOverSSHToARaspberryPiIsButter.aspx (not done any dev for a few months so it may a bit cleaner now.

Comment: I am using  the evil Windows 10 and Rpi Pi Pico W, while waiting for Rpi 5B.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using PyCharm. It supports both Windows and Linux.
It has a remote debug feature (not free). You can have a trial license for 30-day.

Comment: PyCharm community edition is free.

Comment: For community edition, there is no remote debug feature.